# Equicontinuity + pointwise convergence implies uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity

Let $f_n$ be an equicontinuous sequence of functions on a compact interval $D$ and suppose $f_n \to f$ pointwise.

I wrote what I think is a solution, but I never used the assumption that $D$ was compact, so I think it's wrong.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Consider an arbitrary $x \in D$ and some $y$ such that $|x - y| < \delta$, where $\delta$ was the same one from equicontinuity definition.

Now, let $N = \sup_{x \in D}\{N_1:\text{pointwise convergence holds $\forall n \geq N_1$}\}$. Then, for all $n > N$, we have that

$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)| + |f(y) - f(x)| \leq \frac \varepsilon {3} + \frac \varepsilon {3} + \frac \varepsilon {3} = \varepsilon$$

where the first fraction follows from the equicontinuity and the second follows from the pointwise convergence, as $n > N \geq N'$ where $N'$ would have been the $N'$ such that $\forall n \geq N'$, $|f_n(y) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$, and the third term follows if you take limit as $n \to \infty$ of equicontinuity.

Is this right, and if not, where is the mistake?

Comment: The mistake, or precisely the subtetly is here $N= \sup_{x \in D} \{N_1 : ...\}$ need not be in general finite.

Comment: @DominikKutek you said subtlety, does it mean perhaps with additional argument it could be fixed? I'm thinking it only works if the $f_n$ are uniformly bounded, and don't see it can be salvaged without that assumption

Comment: I mean, you said you didn't use compactness. And that's exactly the assumption you're missing, because if done rigorously, the supremum is not over all $x \in D$, but only over finitelly many $x'$s. Given $\varepsilon,\delta$ you've chosen, try to cover $D$ with intervals $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$. Why we need only finitelly many of them to cover whole $D$?Can you give it a try?

Comment: @DominikKutek I see. We can cover with finitely many points (By Heine Borel, there is a finite subcover, and we can choose a rational from each of these intervals in the subcover? or a different argument), and then take the supremum over those points.

Comment: Exactly, in other words you have finitelly many $\{x_i\}$, say $i \le k$, such that $\{(x_i-\delta,x_i+\delta)\}_{i \le k}$ covers whole $D$. Now, take $N= \sup_{i \le k}\{N(x)\}$ where $N(x)$ is such that for $n \ge N(x)$ you have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \le \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ (now $N$ is finite as supremum over finite set). Taking arbitrary point $y \in D$ you have some $x_i$ such that $|x_i-y| < \delta$. And your reasoning ends the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove uniform continuity.
Let $\varepsilon > 0$.
By equicontinuity, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x, y \in D$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
 \lvert x - y \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f_n(x) - f_n(y) \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
.$$

Then, taking limit as $n \to \infty$.
$$
 \lvert x - y \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \le  \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon
.$$

PD: Note that there is no need for $D$ to be compact.
Moreover, It's only needed to be pointwise convergent in a dense set in D.

Comment: The condition that you have used is not equicontinuity. It's *uniform* equicontinuity.